# How difficult is it to impose a differential structure on a fractal?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, fractals, geometric-topology, geometric-measure-theory

Assuming we have a 4-dimensional smooth manifold $M$ embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ that is difficult to understand its differential structure. For convenience's sake we can assume it is compact, simply connected and has non-degenerate intersection form. Suppose we 'approximate' the given manifold by a sequence of compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ such that:

$$N_{i}\subset M,\;\; |\dim(N_{i})-4|<\frac{1}{i},\;\;
\mu(M-N_{i})<\epsilon_{i},\;\;
\epsilon_{i}\rightarrow 0$$
Here we are using Hausdorff dimension.

I asked an Geometric Analysis Professor on this problem, and he said the limit of $N_{i}$ might not tell us anything about $M$, especially $N_{i}$ has far worse analytical properties than $M$. So my question is - can we put a nice differentiable structure on $N_{i}$ such that the above limit makes some sense? For example, the unit real line may be 'approximated' by various fat Cantor sets. This question is quite unclear to me, so I wish to discuss at here.

Comment: Which measure is $\mu$? If $M$ and $N_i$ are of different dimensions then I don't think that this can work.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are going for, but I think that the answer is "very, very difficult."  Strichartz has [a book](https://books.google.com/books?id=CNWJRvXAdhAC&printsec=frontcover&dq=strichartz+analysis+on+fractals&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiZoeT04ZHWAhVJ1WMKHWPnAIsQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=strichartz%20analysis%20on%20fractals&f=false) on the topic (or, at least, on a related topic).